# If $\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_i^n=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, then $\lambda_i=0\;\forall i=1,2,...,r$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> If $\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_i^n=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, then show that $\lambda_i=0\space\forall i=1,2,...,r$.

I have done it assuming $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_r$ are roots of an $r$-degree polynomial and then showing that the given condition implies that all coefficients of this polynomial, except the one of $x^r$, is $0$, giving us the polynomial $f(x)=x^r$ whose roots are all $0$, hence $\lambda_i=0$ $\forall i=1,2,...,r$.

However, I got the following solution from a friend of mine:

> Consider the vectors $a_i=(\lambda_1^i,...,\lambda_r^i)$ for each $i\in\mathbb N$. Then, there are elements of $\mathbb C^r$, which can have $k$ basis elements for some finite $k$. Now, the dot product of any two of these $a_i$ yields $0$, implying that these vectors are linearly independent, so infinitely many linearly independent vectors have been achieved. This is a contradiction.

Is this correct?  I think there's a problem with this solution. I don't think dot product is a valid inner product in $\mathbb C^r$, because it does not give a norm, while every inner product should give a norm. Here $<x,x>=0$ does not necessarily mean $x=0$ where $x\in\mathbb C^r$.

So the orthogonality argument w.r.t. "dot product" is rendered meaningless here.

Comment: The problem is not with the dot product. The problem is that the argument doesn't make any sense as it is written. The assumption is that all the $(\lambda_1^i,\dotsc,\lambda_r^i)$ are orthogonal to the one vector $(1,\dotsc,1)$, not that they are mutually orthogonal - the dot product of two such vectors would be $$\sum_{\rho = 1}^r \lambda_{\rho}^i \overline{\lambda_{\rho}}^j,$$ not $\sum \lambda_{\rho}^{i+j}$. The bilinear form $(z,w) \mapsto \sum z_{\rho}w_{\rho}$ has isotropic vectors, despite being nondegenerate.

Comment: Is that true if hypothesis is weakened to even n?

Comment: @BCLC Then this case gives you $\lambda_i^2 = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was just wondering why this says for all n. So it's true for all even n so let's just say for all odd n?

Comment: @BCLC Then look at $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = (1,-1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer you mean the proposition is false?

Comment: @BCLC Which proposition? The condition that $\sum \lambda_\rho^{2k+1} = 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ does not imply $\lambda_1 = \dotsc = \lambda_r = 0$ is what that example shows.

Comment: @DanielFischer The one in the box in OP: true or false?

Comment: @BCLC That one's true.

Comment: @DanielFischer why does your 1,-1 not disprove it?

Comment: @BCLC Because $1^2 + (-1)^2 = 2 \neq 0$, those $\lambda_i$ don't satisfy the conditions given in the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh how dumb of me. I get mixed up with those for all's again. Thanks ^-^ Wait so if it holds for all n then it holds for all even n and therefore the conclusion follows? Right so the hypothesis is unnecessarily strong?

Comment: @BCLC Since $\lambda^k = 0 \implies \lambda = 0$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it suffices to demand that there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $\sum \lambda_i^{k\cdot n} = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, which looks formally weaker than the condition in the OP. But the proof of that reduces the problem to the situation in the OP by looking at the $\lambda_i^k$ instead at the $\lambda_i$ themselves. So the formally weaker looking condition is not actually weaker.

Comment: My friend said specifically that the dot product is $a.b$, not $a.\bar{b}$. Hence it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an argument similar to the one you suggest you have used. Assume that none of the $\lambda_i$ is equal to $0$ (by throwing away the zeros, which obviously make no difference to the condition). Now, consider an operator $M$ whose eigenvalues are the $\lambda_i.$ By Cayley-Hamilton, this satisfies its minimal polynomial, so $p(M) = 0.$ By taking traces of both sides, you see that the constant term is zero (since the trace of $I$ is not zero). But that means that $0$ *is* an eigenvalue of $M,$ contrary to the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend's argument fails as stated in some comments and answers.  There is still a linear-algebraic argument.

Suppose that $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\ldots$, $\lambda_k$ are all the pairwise distinct nonzero elements of the collection $\left(\lambda_i\right)_{i=1}^r$ (where we have reordered the entries, if necessary).  Let $m_0$ denote the number of zero entries of $\left(\lambda_i\right)_{i=1}^r$.   Assume that $\lambda_i$ occurs with multiplicity $m_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ (so that $\sum_{i=0}^k\,m_i=r$).  We claim that $k=0$.  That is, $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,r$.

Suppose contrary that $k>0$.  Let $\mathrm{V}$ be the modified Vandemonde matrix $\left[\lambda_i^j\right]_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}}$.  Then, $\mathrm{Vx}=\boldsymbol{0}$, where $\mathrm{x}:=\left(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k\right)$.  Note that $\mathbf{V}$ is invertible because $$\det(\mathbf{V})=\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\,\lambda_i\right)\left(\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq k}\,\left(\lambda_i-\lambda_j\right)\right)\neq 0\,.$$
Thus, $\mathbf{x}=\boldsymbol{0}$, but each $m_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ must be a positive integer.  We have a contradiction, and so $k=0$.  The proof is now complete.

In general we have the following statement.

> Let $r$ be a positive integer.  Suppose that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_r$ are pairwise distinct elements of a field $\mathbb{K}$ such that there are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_r\in \mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\}$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^r\,\alpha_i\lambda_i^n=0$ holds for each positive integer $n$.  Then, $r=1$ and $\lambda_1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what the inner product on $\mathbb{C}^r$ is. You should have
$$\langle x,x\rangle=\overline{x}^T\cdot x$$
which is nondegenerate.